# Multer upload an image to node js server (Github as storage)

Tags: node.js, multer

I deployed a web based application but the multer upload doesn't work. It does work in localhost there is no error but the file/s are not save in my director. Here is my code:

```
const multer = require("multer");

 const imageFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
 if (file.mimetype.startsWith("image")) {
  cb(null, true);
 } else {
  cb("Please upload only images.", false);
 }
};

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: (req, file, cb) => {
  cb(null, __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/uploads/");
 },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
   cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

 var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: imageFilter });
 module.exports = uploadFile;
```

Comment: Did you mean `__dirname` instead of `__basedir`

Comment: it's working well in localhost. I am using __basedir but does it have an effect in deployment ?

Comment: __dirname doesn't work either.

Comment: what are the errors that you get?
I think you dont have permission + this folder not exists

Comment: I am not getting any errors everything seems fine. My code and folder is in github storage. The folder exists in my github repo. What do you think might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What happen is the `__basedir` expression will cause "Uncaught ReferenceError: __basedir is not defined" error, but it's silently eaten in the code. To get the error to properly propagate, try adding try-catch block around the offending line this:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    try {
      cb(null, __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/uploads/");
    } catch (e) {
      cb(e);
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
  }
});
```